# Getting all tangled up in json_encode/json_parse and escaping

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, escaping

I have problems when users input " or \ on a html form

The inputted text will be shown again to the user in html content and html attribute contexts

I have the following data flow:

1. jQuery form line input
2. $_POST
3. escape for html attribute: function escapes either with html entities or hex entities (`&quot;` or `&#x5C;`)
4. json_encode in php
5. some unknown javascript interference which blows the fuses
6. json_parse in a jquery ajax callback

The goal is to show the user the exact same text as they inputted, but to escape properly to avoid xss attacks.

Now first thing I got was that $_POST had slashes added for some reason. So I now use stripslashes first. That solved everything for single quotes, but if the user inputs " or \ it still breaks.

The problems seems to be that javascript does some decoding before the json_parse gets the data. it turns the hex escapes back to \ and " thus killing json_parse.

So then I thought if between step 4 and 5 I use htmlspecialchars( $data, NO_QUOTES, 'utf-8' ) I encode the ampersands to `&amp;`, which should neutralise the javascript decoding, but no. It doesn't decode `&amp;`for some reason while it does decode &quot and the hex encodings...

Where am I going wrong?
Is there a way to know exactly what the javascipt decodes and neutralize it from php?

---

What I'm doing now, after wasting half a day:

I think it's probably some jQuery thing to interfere with the data before the onsuccess handler gets it. I have no time to dig it up and kill it right now, so I'm just sneaking past it with a hack that means 3 string transformations just to keep a string untransformed, but hey, developer time is a rare commodity here.

in php:

```
    // due to a problem with the jQuery callback code which seems to decode html entities and hex entities except for &amp;
    // we need to do something to keep our data intact, otherwise parse_json chokes on unescaped backslashes
    // and quotes. So we mask the entity by transforming the & into &amp; here and back in js.
    // TODO: unit test this to prevent regression
    // TODO: debug the jQuery to avoid this workaround
    //
    // echo  json_encode( $response );
    echo preg_replace( '/&/u', '&amp;', json_encode( $response ) );
```

in js before parse_json:

```
    // due to a problem with the jQuery callback code which seems to decode html entities and hex entities except for &amp;
    // we need to do something to keep our data intact, otherwise parse_json chokes on unescaped backslashes
    // and quotes. So we mask the entity by transforming the & into &amp; here and back in js.
    // See function xxxxxx() in file xxxxx.php for the corresponding transformation
    //
    responseText = responseText.replace( /&amp;/g, '&' );
```

I couldn't be bothered at the moment to write the unit tests for it, but I don't seem to be able to break it.

The true question remains how can I knock out the unwanted transformation while getting the same result?

Comment: Can you please try http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp on user Input before sending it to PHP

Comment: @user868766 — That function is deprecated. It should not be used.

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" — You've got half a dozen steps. Go through each one in turn and see where the data stops being formatted the way you expect.

Comment: You shouldn't be encoding for HTML just before you put data into JSON. You should encode for HTML just before you put data into HTML.

Comment: @Quentin : Thanks i was not aware of it.

Comment: @Quentin: well, in a question of steps it's step 5 obviously. I would prefer an encoding my data for each step so that the value of it just before and just after is identical. It just needs to be transported, not changed. If I need to do the escaping on the client side, I need to include [a client side escaping library](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Guidelines_for_Developing_Secure_Applications_Utilizing_JavaScript), which means yet another dependency. Just because I can't get bits transported without having them changed.

Comment: Json in itself is fine actually. All it wants escaped is " and \, which I can do manually if I have to. I'm now thinking maybe it's jQuery that is transforming. I'm trying out possibilities with the ajax options, and now I'll try to use non jquery ajax to see if that alleviates.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off "Magic Quotes" in php. That way the data comes in through $_POST just like the user typed it. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Then you can escape it according to your needs.

Comment: well, thanks for the tip, but according to phpinfo() magic_quotes_gpc is off. Other than that, that doesn't solve the javascript hassle.

Comment: I too spent half a day struggling with backslashes appearing in JSON and eventually turned up here. Thank you very much, @alexwells, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like your problem and used utf8_encode() function. Now it works well. Can you try it ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to change a thing. Anyways, my data is already utf-8 and I don't like the idea of using random functions for things they aren't meant for.